# Как освоить русскую грамматику и лексику учителю математики?

Tags: грамматика, недопустимая-метка, математика

Работаю учителем в школе. Русский для меня второй язык. Веду уроки математики на своем родном языке. Но я также хотел бы вести уроки на русском, а в моей речи очень много грамматических ошибок, и также не знаю ряд математических терминов. Что посоветуете делать? Смогу ли я дома самостоятельно улучшить? Или есть такие спец курсы. Пока я не нашел.

Comment: Может быть попробовать прочесть книги по математике, если вам нужен именно специализированный русский, а не вообще. Термины в целом стандартизированы через английский язык, так что вам нужно знать английский и переводы на русский. Насчет курсов, возможно в вузах есть курсы специализированного языка, но опять же русский-английский либо попробовать найти преподавателей из технических вузов. Но опять же не ясно, какой у вас родной язык.

Answer (score 1):

Овладевать «математической речью», чтобы грамотно и понятно произносить на русском языке записи математических формул и выражений, содержащих: знаки арифметических  действий, символы математических функций, обозначения переменных в виде  латинских букв, числа, записанные цифрами, - приходится всем без исключения, в том числе и тем, для кого русский язык родной.
Попытки помочь в самостоятельном овладении математической речью предприняты:

- здесь: https://foxford.ru/wiki/matematika/chislovie-i-bukvennie-virazhenia
- и здесь: https://folkmap.ru/articles/pravila-chteniya-matematicheskih-vyrazheniy.html
- и здесь: https://math-prosto.ru/ru/pages/reports/reports_sub_level_2/how_to_pronounce_terms_in_mathematics/

Answer (score 1):

Мне довелось пройти через это, когда едва окончив аспирантуру в англоязычной стране, я был вынужден приступить к преподаванию по-английски -- при том, что мой английский был не очень хорош.

Чтобы оперативно решить этот вопрос, я одновременно проводил работу по двум направлениям.  Во-первых, читая учебники и научные статьи, я начал выписывать термины и просто понравившиеся мне речевые обороты.  Во-вторых, я стал параллельно читать художественные тексты -- и, опять же, выписывать понравившиеся слова и фразы.  Но именно понравившиеся, вкусные.  Ибо случайную фразу труднее запомнить -- а фраза понравившаяся, элегантная легко остаётся в памяти.

Именно параллельная работа по двум направлениям помогла мне за относительно короткое время вывести свой язык на подобающий уровень.

Источники, содержащие математическую лексику, указаны выше в ответе guaranteen`а.

Источником для работы по второму направлению может стать любая хорошая книга.  Хорошая прежде всего в смысле стиля.  Стиль должен быть таким, чтобы фразы ложились на сердце и сами запоминались.  (Лично для меня таким источником могла бы стать "Белая Гвардия" Булгакова, но это, разумеется, вопрос вкуса.)